# SQLite: Transposing results of a GROUP BY and filling in IDs with names

Tags: python, sqlite, pivot

My question is rather specific, if you have a better title please suggest one. Also, formatting is bad - didn't know how to combine lists and codeblocks.

I have an SQLite3 database with the following (relevant parts of the) .schema:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, user TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE locations (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE purchases (location_id INTEGER, user_id INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE sales (location_id integer, user_id INTEGER);
```

`purchases` has about 4.5mil entries, `users` about 300k, `sales` about 100k, and `locations` about 250 - just to gauge the data volume.

My desired use would be to generate a JSON object to be handed off to another application, very much condensed in volume by doing the following:

-GROUPing both purchases and sales into one common table BY location_id,user_id - IOW, getting the number of "actions" per user per location. That I can do, result is something like

```
loc  | usid  | loccount
-----------------------
1    | 1246  | 123
1    | 2345  | 1
13   | 1246  | 46
13   | 8732  | 4
27   | 2345  | 41
```

(At least it *looks* good, always hard to tell with such volumes; query:

```
select location_id,user_id,count(location_id) from
  (select location_id,user_id from purchases
     union all
   select location_id,user_id from sales)
group by location_id,user_id order by user_id`
```

)

-Then, transposing that giant table such that I would get:

```
usid | loc1 | loc13 | loc27
---------------------------
1246 | 123  | 46    | 0
2345 | 1    | 0     | 41
8732 | 0    | 4     | 0
```

That I cannot do, and it's my absolutely crucial point for this question. I tried some things I found online, especially here, but I just started SQLite a little while ago and don't understand many queries.

-Lastly, translate the table into plain text in order to write it to JSON:

```
user | AAAA | BBBBB | CCCCC
---------------------------
zeta | 123  | 46    | 0
beta | 1    | 0     | 41
iota | 0    | 4     | 0
```

That I *probably* could do with quite a bit of experimentation and inner join, although I'm always very unsure what way is the best approach to handle such data volumes, hence I wouldn't mind a pointer.

The whole thing is written in Python's sqlite3 interface, if it matters. In the end, I'd love to have something I could just do a "for" loop per user over in order to generate the JSON, which would then of course be very simple. It doesn't matter if the query takes a long time (<10min would be nice), it's only run twice per day as a sort of backup. I've only got a tiny VPS available, but being limited to a single core the performance is as good as on my reasonably powerful desktop. (i5-3570k running Debian.)

The table headers are just examples because I wasn't quite sure if I could use integers for them (didn't discover the syntax if so), as long as I'm somehow able to look up the numeric part in the locations table I'm fine. Same for translating the user IDs into names. The number of columns is known beforehand - they're after all just INTEGER PRIMARY KEYs and I have a `list()` of them from some other operation. The number of rows can be determined reasonably quickly, ~3s, if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using subqueries to achieve your desired transposed output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.usid,

   IFNULL((SELECT t1.loccount FROM tablename t1 
         WHERE t1.usid = m.usid AND t1.loc=1),0) AS Loc1,
   IFNULL((SELECT t2.loccount FROM tablename t2 
         WHERE t2.usid = m.usid AND t2.loc=13),0) AS Loc13,
   IFNULL((SELECT t3.loccount FROM tablename t3 
         WHERE t3.usid = m.usid AND t3.loc=27),0) AS Loc27

FROM tablename As m
```

Alternatively, you can use nested `IF` statements (or in the case of SQLite that uses `CASE/WHEN`) as derived table:

```
SELECT temp.usid, Max(temp.loc1) As Loc1, 
       Max(temp.loc13) As Loc13, Max(temp.loc27) As Loc27
FROM    
   (SELECT tablename.usid, 
      CASE WHEN loc=1 THEN loccount ELSE 0 As Loc1 END,  
      CASE WHEN loc=13 THEN loccount ELSE 0 As Loc13 END, 
      CASE WHEN loc=27 THEN loccount ELSE 0 As Loc27 END
    FROM tablename) AS temp    
GROUP BY temp.usid
```

Comment: Trying to implement this with the background of the grouping step is giving me a headache, to be honest. You seem to assume an existing table - would it be better to INSERT the results of the first step into a temporary one? Right now, I attempt to do this with a VIEW containing the above query, and besides not working, it's abysmally slow. (I simply substituted my VIEW where you used m.)

Edit: Oh, and by the way - if I didn't misinterpret your query, you're missing a comma after m.usid.

Comment: Alright, I tried this on the whole DB with the results of the first query in a temp table, and it works but is unfeasibly slow - takes about 5s per user, which would make it less than practical for a few hundred thousand. Too bad. Thank you for your response, though! Because I'm not too familiar with SO's etiquette: Responses are only upvoted if they were a practical solution, right? Not as a "thank you" or if they would be useful in another context.

Comment: But you mention: "It doesn't matter if the query takes a long time (<10min would be nice)."

Comment: Nonetheless, I add another solution. Also, please re-run the subquery as I made a tiny overlook in the subquery's `loc` table reference and it needed a `DISTINCT` (since usids repeat).

Comment: Amazing, the second query is blazing fast - a few seconds even without a static temporary table! Thanks a lot!  (And "a long time" is an hour at most in computational terms for me, while your first query would have taken over 19 days at full CPU usage.)